# What happened to Exposé?

Tags: macos, window-manager, mission-control, expose

Before Lion I used Exposé daily. Now with Lion it's gone and Mission Control is in its place. Now when I use MC it groups all my open pages instead of showing each page. This is kind of a pain when swapping between applications.  Is there a way I can use a Hot Key or pointer swipe to show ALL of my open pages, spanning different applications?

Comment: Wasn't Exposé replaced by Mission Control?

Comment: are you using a desktop or portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a reliable way to use the old Exposé on Lion.

You can, however, use Mission Control to access all of your open windows easily.

In Mission Control, hover over an app's 'cluster' of open windows. Use a two-finger swipe upwards (or scroll up with a scroll wheel) to separate those windows for easier access.

You can access all of an app's windows using <kbd>F10</kbd>. You can assign a Hot Corner or different shortcut using System Preferences-> Mission Control (this function is known as "Application Windows").
From here, you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to see other application's windows.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I'm on the new Air and love it. I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 1):

In OS X 10.7, Exposé has been outmoded by Mission Control. It essentially combines Exposé and Spaces into one set of gestures. How you access it will depend on your computer and its configuration.

MacBooks with glass, buttonless trackpads and desktops with the Magic Trackpad can access it by swiping four fingers up, I believe. Older MacBooks that run Lion can access it with the Exposé button on the keyboard. And, of course, all Macs can be configured to launch Mission Control by moving the cursor to a corner. It can all be accessed via the Mission Control pane in the System Preferences.